# Blog post on new KOMAscript release (v3.11), with new English manual

Tags: support, blog

For once I'd like to make a blog post:

---

*Markus Kohm*, maintainer of [KOMAscript](http://www.komascript.de/) has published a new version ([3.11](http://www.komascript.de/release3.11)) of the KOMAscript bundle. There is one extraordinary issue: The new version includes a new manual in English language. Markus said on his [webpage](http://www.komascript.de/release3.11):

> »A new English user manual with the same structure and completely
>   translated content of the German user manual is provided. There are
>   still several issues with the translation, nevertheless, it's much
>   better than the previous English manual.«

As far as I can see, all the features of KOMAscript 3 are documented, same way as in the German version.

Comment: You should get a mail from the blog system soon :-)

Comment: Could you post a short biog that I can add to the 'Authors' page?

Comment: @JosephWright »Keks Dose« is the nick of Alexander W., a German lawyer in the windenergy business. He has unfortunately no programming skills, nonetheless he uses Emacs, Orgmode + LaTeX for nearly anything.

Comment: @KeksDose: great blog post, my friend! Welcome aboard! `:)`